# Symfony LTS: how to upgrade from 2.8 to 3.4?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8, symfony-3.4

Symfony 2.8 is the last release of the `2.x` branch and the previous LTS.

Symfony 3.4 is the last release of the `3.x` branch and the current LTS.

What steps are required in order to upgrade Symfony from `2.8` to `3.4` and switch to this last LTS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Prepare upgrade

Check that all the dependencies and bundles listed in `composer.json` have published a version compatible with Symfony 3.4, you can do this by searching each package on Packagist, for example [EasyAdmin](https://packagist.org/packages/easycorp/easyadmin-bundle) is compatible with Symfony 3 because the dependencies in the `requires` are not limited to Symfony 2 (we would see something like `symfony/*: ~2.3`). If one of the dependencies it not compatible with Symfony 3, you'll have to find replacement packages or patch these libraries.

## composer.json

In order to upgrade you app from Symfony `2.8` to Symfony `3.4` you'll have to update your dependencies by changing your <kbd>composer.json</kbd> file:

(`[…]` indicates unchanged code)

Old ([2.8](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.8/composer.json)) version:

```json
{
    […]
    "autoload-dev": {
        "files": [ "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php" ]
     },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3,>=2.3.10",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin",
        "platform": {
            "php": "5.6"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        […]
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.8-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

New ([3.4](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/3.4/composer.json)) version:

```json
{
    […]
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": { "Tests\\": "tests/" },
        "files": [ "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php" ]
     },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "5.6"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },

    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        […]
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "3.4-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

## Summary

- `autoload-dev.psr-4` has been added (it has to be changed with the path to your tests directory)
- Symfony and dependencies are updated
- `symfony/polyfill-apcu` is a new dependency
- `extra` has been updated in order to use new directory structure: `var` for temporary files, etc.
- `config.bin-dir` has been removed

More details about upgrades: [→ 3.0](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/UPGRADE-3.0.md#frameworkbundle), [→ 3.1](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/UPGRADE-3.1.md#frameworkbundle), [→ 3.2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/UPGRADE-3.2.md#frameworkbundle), [→ 3.3](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/UPGRADE-3.3.md#frameworkbundle), [→ 3.4](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/UPGRADE-3.4.md#frameworkbundle)

## app/AppKernel.php

Add `getRootDir` and update `registerContainerConfiguration` functions:

```json
public function getRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__;
}

public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
}
```

## Cache and logs

If you want to put `cache` and `logs` in `var/`, you have to update your `app/AppKernel.php` file by adding the following lines:

```json
public function getCacheDir()
{
    return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
}
public function getLogDir()
{
    return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';
}
```

Then create the `var/` directory and put an empty file `.gitkeep`

And apply these changes to your `.gitignore` file:

```json
/var/cache/*
/var/logs/*
!var/cache/.gitkeep
!var/logs/.gitkeep
```

See also: [What is the new Symfony 3 directory structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23994473/2257664)

## Final steps

Once you have updated your <kbd>composer.json</kbd> file, you have to update the dependencies:

```json
composer update
```

Then you may need to flush the cache:

```json
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev
```

Note: I used the following command in order to get the <kbd>composer.json</kbd> files:

```json
# create Symfony "2.8.*" project in the "2.8" directory
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition "2.8" "2.8.*" --no-interaction -v
# create Symfony "3.4.*" project in the "3.4" directory
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition "3.4" "3.4.*" --no-interaction -v
# compare the Symfony 2.8 and 3.4 composer.json files
diff -u 2.8/composer.json 3.4/composer.json
```

The diff is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/compare/2.8...3.4#diff-b5d0ee8c97c7abd7e3fa29b9a27d1780) too.

Bonus: [enable autowiring of services](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49941811/2257664).

Comment: So posting a question and then immediately answering it in this level of detail is a thing now?  And you completely overlooked third party dependencies.  That is often the real challenge.

Comment: @Cerad my [previous guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570276/symfony2-lts-how-to-upgrade-from-2-3-to-2-7) was well accepted and there's nothing wrong in [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I wrote this answer while updating one of my projects (with few dependencies) and it worked for me so I thought that it may help some other users. I agree that upgrading third party dependencies is the hardest part but I can't explain specific steps for every bundle.

Comment: @Cerad I added a note about dependencies, thanks for your input!

Answer (score 5):

### 2019+ Instant Upgrades Version

Today, you can automate most of the work with instant upgrade tool called *Rector* (I'm author of). It has prepared sets for many frameworks, the Symfony ones are most complete. Also include PHP upgrade, that you might need.

**You can read more about this particular upgrade path in: [How to Upgrade Symfony 2.8 to 3.4](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2019/02/28/how-to-upgrade-symfony-2-8-to-3-4/)**

Comment: - Installation request for rector/rector ^0.6.14 -> satisfiable by rector/rector[v0.6.14].    - rector/rector v0.6.14 requires symfony/process ^4.4|^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.4.0, v4.4.1, v4.4.2, v4.4.3, v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3]. - Installation request for symfony/symfony (locked at v2.8.52, required as 2.8.*) -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.8.52].

Comment: https://getrector.org/blog/2020/01/20/how-to-install-rector-despite-composer-conflicts